# Why is the disney logo in Hercules the cgi intro while the Emperor's New Groove uses older logo?

Tags: disney, hercules-1997, the-emperors-new-groove

I was re-watching The Emperor's New Groove and noticed that it used the old Disney castle intro where the castle is filled in on a blue background from the top down.  This is different than the Disney castle intro to Hercules which uses the CGI landscape castle.  I checked and found Hercules came out 3 years before Emperor's New Groove and almost a decade before that intro was used on another movie for the first time.   Did Disney change the intro to Hercules when it was released on blu-ray or was the CGI logo first introduced with this movie?

Comment: Because they choose which logo to use for each movie. Just depends on how they feel.

Comment: I'm totally confident - though I have no evidence other than my memory - that when *Hercules* was released in 1997, it used the older Disney logo.  They must have changed this for the reissue.

Comment: This would be an easy check if someone has a VHS copy of Hercules (and a VCR to play the tape).

Answer (score 2):

[This page](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Walt_Disney_Pictures_logo) documents the evolution of the intro logo. The full cgi logo was first used in 2006 with *Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man's Chest*. Further down under the 2011 variant it says this:

> Later reissues of classic Disney movies released on DVD and Blu-ray
> began using this or the original 2006 variant.

So *Hercules* originally used the 2D version, but was later changed for rereleases.